# Backspace Fails to clear values on input type='email' When there is a <SPACE> in the email Field

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, html-input

If there is a ' ' space in the email field pressing Backspace takes the Pointer Back to the start of the Input Field without deleting the Text before the ' ' space.
I'm using this Input Tag for React so This really messes up the State value.

[Before Backspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaHqn.png)

[After Backspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYm5E.png)

Comment: show your code here

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and how to create [mcve].